# what is a better way of switching panels in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that swaps panels when a button is pressed, hiding any others that might be on the screen before displaying the next. it is a bit messy because of the way it has to be worked around to prevent both panels from appearing at once.

http://jsfiddle.net/zDeveloper/X4sMF/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pref-sliders-swap").appendTo($("#sliderbox"));
    $("#sliderbox").hide();
    $("#characters").hide();
    $("#currentdesires").hide();
    $("#important").hide();

    $("#sliderbutton").click(function () {
        $("#welcome").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#characters").fadeOut(function () {
                $("#currentdesires").fadeOut(function () {
                    $("#important").fadeOut(function () {
                        $("#sliderbox").fadeIn();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

    $("#homebutton").click(function () {
        $("#sliderbox").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#characters").fadeOut(function () {    
                $("#currentdesires").fadeOut(function () {
                    $("#important").fadeOut(function () {
                        $("#welcome").fadeIn();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

    $("#charactersbutton").click(function () {
        $("#sliderbox").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#welcome").fadeOut(function () {
                $("#currentdesires").fadeOut(function () {
                    $("#important").fadeOut(function () {
                        $("#characters").fadeIn();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });    

    $("#desirebutton").click(function () {
        $("#sliderbox").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#welcome").fadeOut(function () {
                $("#characters").fadeOut(function () {
                    $("#important").fadeOut(function () {
                        $("#currentdesires").fadeIn();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

    $("#impbutton").click(function () {
        $("#sliderbox").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#welcome").fadeOut(function () {
                $("#characters").fadeOut(function () {
                    $("#currentdesires").fadeOut(function () {
                        $("#important").fadeIn();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

});
```

The code I have placed there does exactly what I want,smoothly fading in and out the panels(at least in firefox) though it is a bit cumbersome. is there a better way to acheive the same effect?

Comment: where is your html? can you share that also

Comment: bit hard to see without the appropriate HTML also. Consider putting it in jsfiddle.net instead of pastebin.

Comment: also post your code in the question

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EJkxk/2/ - it is a skeleton of how to do it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zDeveloper/X4sMF/

Comment: @ZCoder check my fiddle

Comment: Please include relevant code directly in your question as a priority; a link to a fiddle is a desirable but optional extra. Also, _indent your code..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<!--use the class trigger to group the trigger elements, then use data-target to specify the id of the target element to be displayed-->
<div id="sliderbutton" data-target="#sliderbox" class="trigger">sliderbutton</div>
<div id="homebutton" data-target="#welcome" class="trigger">homebutton</div>
<div id="charactersbutton" data-target="#characters" class="trigger">charactersbutton</div>
<div id="desirebutton" data-target="#currentdesires" class="trigger">desirebutton</div>
<div id="impbutton" data-target="#important" class="trigger">impbutton</div>

<!--Use the class content to group all the content elements-->
<div id="sliderbox" class="content">sliderbox</div>
<div id="characters" class="content">characters</div>
<div id="currentdesires" class="content">currentdesires</div>
<div id="important" class="content">important</div>
<div id="welcome" class="content">welcome</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("#pref-sliders-swap").appendTo("#sliderbox");
    $(".content").not('#welcome').hide();

    var $contents = $('.content');
    $contents.not('#welcome').hide();

    $(".trigger").click(function () {
        var $visible = $contents.stop(true, true).filter(':visible'),
            $target = $($(this).data('target')).stop(true, true);
        if ($visible.length) {
            $visible.fadeOut(function () {
                $target.fadeIn();
            });
        } else {
            $target.fadeIn();
        }
    });

})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EJkxk/)